# Error C4789 from Visual Studio 2017 linker

Tags: c++, visual-studio

This is 64-bit Windows 7, Visual Studio 2017, C++ project.

When I do a release build with compiler option `/sdl` I am getting error 4789 (this is a warning if `/sdl` is not enabled).

```
1>Finished searching libraries
1>Generating code
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.10586.0\ucrt\corecrt_memcpy_s.h(50): error C4789: buffer 'buffer' of size 262144 bytes will be overrun; 262143 bytes will be written starting at offset 2
1>All 2506 functions were compiled because no usable IPDB/IOBJ from previous compilation was found.
```

I'd like to track down the cause of the error. Reading the MS docs on C4789 suggests there is one of the functions `memset`, `wmemset`, `memcpy` or `strcpy` which specifies an operation length > destination length. Further, this must be known at compile/link time, meaning that both the destination size and operation length are constants.

My difficulty is that there are literally hundreds of uses of the named functions in my project, and the linker does not identify which one is erroneous. I also searched for only those with a destination named '`buffer`', with no luck.

Is there any way to narrow down the cause of the error?

Comment: How many places do you have a buffer of 262144 bytes?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken your error lead states:  corecrt_memcpy_s.h(50):   Would you possibly conclude that that memcpy is at issue?   You could find that source and increase the buffer size...

Comment: @Retired Ninja: I can't find any.

Comment: @Dr t: The function is one that invokes corecrt_memcpy_s, which is part of the C++ runtime. How do I locate the offending function in my code? Per MSDN, all 4 functions that I named could be at fault.

Comment: This had me thinking it was a linker buffer and a bug so i did some looking and found a link with a work-around that you might be able to use...https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3b1a8f56-5a5d-4e0a-be73-14993bae3b0e/buffer-overrun-c4789-when-using-stdinitializerlistt-as-default-argument-a-known-compiler?forum=vclanguage  You have to read down in the discussion a ways to find the work-around.  good luck...

Comment: @Dr t: I had already read this. It is a similar bug in the linker, but it was fixed by MS years ago.

Comment: You can get an idea if it is a linker buffer if you compile/link with empty initializer list(s) if possible.  Otherwise may be a new bug...like the old one in VS2014

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149905/discussion-between-woody20-and-dr-t).

Comment: I copy pasted my code into a separate document, deleted the file in Visual Studio, recreated it, and copy-pasted my code back in. That fixed it. You could also try turning off compiler optimizations.